# Equatorial LEO Satellites

Tags: orbit, low-earth-orbit, tracking

Which satellites orbit in an equatorial LEO ($0^{\circ}$ inclination) around Earth? Or where can I find information regarding this that will give me the exact location of that satellite (longitude and latitude) at a specific time?

There are a few live tracking websites but I can not isolate those with an equatorial orbit.

Comment: Related, maybe a duplicate: [Why are there no LEO satellites in the earth's equatorial plane?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31781)

Comment: [One of the answers](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/31826/2752) to the above linked question lists two LEO satellites with very low inclination.

Comment: IXPE is another: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IXPE#Launch_profile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [almost duplicate question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31781/why-are-there-no-leo-satellites-in-the-earths-equatorial-plane/31826#31826) referenced by David Hammen is an excellent resource for some answers to this question.  Defining Equatorial as less than 5 degrees I find just 3 active satellites.  IXPE (49954), AGILE (311335), and ORS-5 (42921) {And I'm not sure AGILE is actually Active}.  Expanding "equatorial" to less than 10 degrees gets you another six or so (thanks to Kwajalein launches which is at 8 deg latitude)

I'll add that I saw this as a challenge to be able to filter/isolate equatorial orbits in some sort of public database, and that is where my answer will focus.  This is surprisingly hard.

- I don't think either [space-track](https://www.space-track.org/) nor [celestrak](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/) have an easy way to filter.  You could download all the [TLEs](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/gp.php?GROUP=active&FORMAT=tle) from celestrak and then write a quick python script that filters TLEs.  These two sites are generally the source of data for all other satellite tracking web sites.
- Jonathan McDowell's excellent (and authoritative) [General Catalog of Artificial Space Objects (GCAT)](https://planet4589.org/space/gcat/web/cat/index.html) does list nominal inclination, apogee and perigee for all objects.  He has a [tab delimited file](https://planet4589.org/space/gcat/tsv/cat/satcat.tsv) that is easy to bring into excel and sort/filter. A [text version](https://planet4589.org/space/gcat/data/cat/satcat.html) viewable in most browsers also exists.  **This is probably the easiest route.**
- AGI's [Systems Toolkit](https://www.ansys.com/products/missions/ansys-stk) (STK) has an "object database" that allows you to search and filter.  Learning curve is a bit steep though.  If you go to the [licensing page](https://licensing.agi.com/stk/), you can request a free 30-day trial.  If you dig through their downloads page, you can get to the downloads for versions 12.2 and older (you may need to sign up on their web site).  It used to be that 12.2 and older provided some basic functionality for free; I' not sure if that is still the case.