# How low is VLEO? (FCC's newest approval for SpaceX)

Tags: spacex, low-earth-orbit, communication-satellite, regulatory, very-low-earth-orbit

Engaget's [SpaceX gets FCC approval to deploy thousands more internet satellites](https://www.engadget.com/2018/11/15/fcc-spacex-starlink-internet-satellites/) says

> SpaceX's plan to build a global, high-speed wireless internet network using satellites has taken another step forward. The FCC approved the company's request to deploy more than 7,000 very-low-Earth orbit satellites for its Starlink network. It follows the regulator giving SpaceX the green light in March to launch 4,425 satellites.
>
> When it's complete, Starlink will be comprised of almost 12,000 satellites that will blanket the planet with a persistent internet connection. That should mean people in rural areas or other locations where more traditional types of connections are impractical can access a network with promised speeds of up to 1 Gbps.

The article links to a November 15, 2018 FCC release [FCC Boosts Satellite Broadband Connectivity and Competition in the United States](https://docs.fcc.gov/public/attachments/DOC-355102A1.pdf). Which mentions approvals for several space companies and constellations.

> In a Memorandum Opinion, Order and Authorization, the Commission granted SpaceX’s
> application with certain conditions, **authorizing SpaceX to construct, deploy, and operate a new very-low-Earth orbit constellation of more than 7,000 satellites using V-band frequencies**. The Commission also granted SpaceX’s request to add the 37.5-42.0 GHz, and 47.2-50.2 GHz frequency bands to its previously authorized NGSO constellation. The Commission’s action provides SpaceX with additional flexibility to provide both diverse geographic coverage and the capacity to support a wide range of broadband and communications services for residential, commercial, institutional, governmental, and professional users in the United States and globally.

---

**Question:** So I'd like to ask *how low is VLEO?* SpaceX's very-low-Earth orbit constellation of more than 7,000 satellites?

I haven't heard the orbit called VLEO yet, but it mush be a lot lower than the orbits of the original 4,425 approved, which are in the 1,100 to 1,300 km ballpark. See [SpaceX's 4,425 satellite constellation - what's the method to the madness?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19055/12102) for details.

[image: SpaceX first 4,425 satellites]

Comment: Also SpaceX revised the orbit for Starlink, down from 1100-1300 to 525Km I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Per Space News](https://spacenews.com/fcc-approves-spacex-telesat-leosat-and-kepler-internet-constellations/), reviewing the applications, VLEO in this context is below 350 km orbit.

> Of the four, SpaceX is by far the largest with 7,518 satellites constituting what it calls a “very low Earth orbit,” or VLEO constellation that would operate slightly below 350-kilometers.

What is interesting to me is the comment that follows:

> At that altitude, SpaceX says atmospheric drag would pull spent satellites down in one month, assuaging concerns about the magnitude of debris that that many satellites could create in higher orbits.

I read that, in a similar comment they made about the main 525Km orbit Starlink plan, that it would reenter in 6 months. Which is to say, unpowered, out of control, it would re-enter in 1-6 months. As opposed to the lifetime of such a satellite would be 1-6 months (for the two cases).

I.e. Once the vehicle is out of fuel to maintain orbit, THEN it has the shortened lifespan.

As you can imagine, a constellation with 7000 satellites that last a total of one month each is impossible or at best improbable.

Comment: How much would it need to stay in orbit longer than a month? If takes an ounce of fuel to keep a 1 pound satellite in orbit 2 years at 350KM, it might be practical.

Comment: An excellent second question.

Comment: Always in another question.  :) as a hint I believe they plan to use Hall effect electric thrusters, so fuel masses may be low enough.

Comment: New related [How much fuel to maintain VLEO for communication satelites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32043/109)