# Spatial screwdriver

Tags: eva

I watched the Kimbrough and Whitson's EVA on 01/06.

And I'm wondering why astronauts use custom screwdriver and not the usual ones (like Makita or Dewalt, for example) ?

[image]
[image]

Is it because of the battery technology ? Rotation speed ? Something else ?

Is there something that makes the usual tools do not work in space ?

Comment: Look up "cold welding" for why all "store-bought" tools are right out. Long story short, if you don't want your screwdriver permanently fused with the screw in void, you need special alloys. Now why the fancy shape - let someone else pick that one.

Comment: Is cold welding an issue on such short timeframes? (inserting a tool into a screw)

Comment: @Hobbes: AFAIK it's a matter of pressure, not time - it's nearly instantaneous if the metals come into contact; the roughness of surface in general case makes it very weak on standard touch/press contact (relatively small percentage of surface comes into contact) but more pressure/torque will cause a solid connection.

Comment: Do these tools moderate or compensate for the torque that comes back to the user? Wouldn't want an astronaut/cosmonaut spinning around a screw that doesn't want to budge.

Comment: Would it really be so hard to fix the cold-welding problem by using coatings or the like?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [Pistol Grip Tool](http://www.techbriefs.com/Briefs/July99/GSC13706.html) has some features not found in DIY or even professional cordless drills. 
It can control its torque and speed exactly, and torque/speed/turn count values can be programmed. It also measures and records the applied torque.

[In general, space tools](http://www.popularmechanics.com/space/a24639/space-drill-used-by-nasa-astronauts/) also need to be usable while wearing thick gloves, and they need to work in extreme temperatures and a vacuum, and they need to be tested to make sure they don't interfere with anything.

Comment: Thanks for the link ! I also found https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/hubble/servicing/series/cats.html which explains why specialty tools are needed

Comment: A tool that remembers you removed the screws and haven't put them back yet [even when you forget](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/1784/12102) may be useful on Earth as well!