# What is this balloon for in this clean room and what is the proper name for the "stand" that is holding the satellite?

Tags: identify-this-object, clean-room

[image]

What is this balloon doing in this clean room and what is the proper name for the "stand" (white & blue) that is holding the satellite?

Comment: Pretty sure the stand is a vibration tester. No idea what the balloon is for, huh.

Comment: No that is not for vibration test. This is >> https://www.isac.gov.in/facility/f-system-3.jsp

Comment: I'd call that a goniometer, but there may be a fancier name for it.

Answer (score 11):

The balloon is used to support parts of the spacecraft that can't hold their own weight in 1 g - booms, appendages, etc.

As you can see from this cropped photo (from [here](https://www.isro.gov.in/sites/default/files/galleries/%E0%A4%9C%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%9F-11%20%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%A8%20%E0%A4%9A%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%20%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%98%E0%A4%BE/gsat-11incleanroom2.jpg)), there is no hose to allow flowing extra gas into the balloon. It is simply connected to the object it supports by a tether.[image]

The stand is called a "positioner" if it allows the spacecraft to be held at multiple angles.  But often just referred to as "fixture" or "stand".

> A 3-axis positioner can also be used. This is an elaborate fixture
>   that holds the spacecraft at multiple angles to measure all mass
>   properties (CG in 3 axes, MOI in 3 axes, and POI in 3 planes). It
>   allows calculation of product of inertia based on moment of inertia
>   measurement, so the entire inertia tensor can be derived with the use
>   of a KSR instrument. The spacecraft positioner also minimizes handling
>   of the spacecraft. The spacecraft is mounted in a vertical
>   orientation; the positioner rotates the spacecraft to the various
>   measurement positions and brings the spacecraft back to vertical for
>   easy dismounting.

More, and examples [here](https://www.space-electronics.com/Industries/spacecraft-satellites)

Comment: If there exist spacecraft components which can't hold their own weight in 1g, how are they going to survive launch?

Comment: @Intellex This is used for appendages that unfold after orbital insertion: antennas, solar panels, etc. It's a completely different loading situation; the folded case handles launch loads.

Comment: Is ISRO the only agency to use balloons, or others too use them?

Comment: It's not unknown; here's another example: https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/i/inflatesail (scroll down)

Comment: I've just asked [How often are helium balloons used to support deployed spacecraft appendages during testing on the ground in Earth gravity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51400/12102)

Answer (score 5):

Having looked at the various ISAC facilities, I suspect that is just an adjustable stand in one of the clean rooms.

Compare to this image search result for 'ISAC clean room':

[image]

The stand is adjustable to give easy access to all areas of the satellite without having to use ladders (which can fall over and damage the satellite).

A similar system (with only 1 degree of freedom) for car bodies is known as a rotisserie: 
[image]

[ISAC](https://www.isac.gov.in/facility/f-system-1.jsp) has removed all images of their test facilities from the HTML of their website, but the images are still there and can be found via an [image search](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&hl=en&tbm=isch&q=clean%20room%20ISAC%20satellite&nfpr=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7lMLh4abgAhWHM-wKHeXgBiQQvgUIPSgB&biw=1324&bih=1092&dpr=1#imgrc=pkEwE_GDp4jBWM:).

Example, this is a vibration test system at ISAC:

[image]

As for the balloon, I haven't found a reference. I suspect it's used to capture overflow helium during filling of the helium tanks in a spacecraft.

Comment: Maybe the helium tanks are "washed" from remaining air by filling them partially and then releasing the mix of helium and air into the balloon until there is only pure helium in the tanks.

Comment: Of course, as we've learned previously, it doesn't prevent damage to the satellite if you forget to bolt it down: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/1783/58

Comment: With reference to this statement "Having looked at the various ISAC facilities..." Are you currently working at ISRO? Sorry to ask an irrelevant question, but it is related to one of my questions.

Comment: No. I only did an image search on the internet.